# Help moving around edges and vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh

(sorry if this is a noob question, I am a noob)
So I want to grab an edge of a cube and push it inward to create a dent in the cube. (I'm trying to put a fuller in a sword model I'm making for context) However, when I do this, it looks like it just creates another set of vertices and leaves the ones I'm trying to move in the same place.

Comment: Hello :). It should work just as you expect. Can you please add an image of your 3D viewport, to better illustrate the issue?

Comment: In the screen captures you provide ... can you read the number of vertices of your [cube?]?... Is it what you think it should be? Do you think you have defective duplicated vertices which can be merged by distance?  Back file up and try merge by distance.There are plenty of video tutorials on the website that has a name that rhymes with noonube.  Make sure you are not extruding vertices by accident.  Try your  work on a simple new mesh ,such as a cube subdivided once. Make sure your maneuvers with an extremely simple object are correct.